# Is there an agreement on the Prophet's birth date?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, muslim-practices, bidah

Is there a disagreement on the popular date of 12 Rabi' Al-Awwal among scholars or among pro-Mawlid Muslims? Are the Fatimids the origin of the date of 12 Rabi' Al-Awwal?

Comment: Yes there is a disagreement between scholars. As a Muslim for me that date doesn't matter, whatever message he delivered is the most important for me

Comment: A helpful lecture (start at time 37:14): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aln07CIO_BM

Answer (score 1):

There is no agreement on Prophet's (peace be upon him) birthday. 
The Fatimids have started Prophet's birthday celebration, but they didn't invent the date. The date 12th Rabi' Al-Awwal is not totally rejected by Sunni Scholars, meaning it is a possible date.

Comment: You should probably elaborate the Sunni opinion and the dates that are most accepted and likely. 12 Rabi Al-Awwal is a possible date but it is not the highest in terms of credibility

Comment: I heard from two shaykhs, both Ph.D in Islamic studies, both studied in Islamic University of Madinah. But one shaykh said 12th is not the most probable date, the other shaykh said 12th is the most most probable date. So now I stop saying which is most probable and which is not. I just say there is disagreement.

Comment: Sure, but if you stopped trying to research a thing if two scholars disagreed on it, you would never learn anything. Although this is a pretty unimportant topic so fair enough.

Comment: I don't ignore studying and learning more. I am a student of Islamic studies already and keep learning, alhamdulillah. When there are so many things to learn, I need to prioritize.